# Lubuntu 13.04 works, except for unpredictable blank screens

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, 13.04, lubuntu, macbook-pro

I just installed Lubuntu 13.04 on my MacBook Pro 6,2.

It seems to work fine. However, once in a while, when I am logged in and using the computer, the screen will suddenly become blank. (Sound still works -- I know this because one time the screen went blank when I was watching a video.)

Does anyone know what might be causing this? (I am using the NVIDIA driver.)

Edit: I have installed Lubuntu 12.04 to see if this would fix the problem; however, the unpredictable blank screen problem is still there.

Comment: Have you checked xScreensaver settings?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the screensaver settings, because: (1) Often, I am at the computer (typing on keyboard or clicking things with the mouse) when the screen goes blank. (2) If the screen went blank because of the screensaver, then I would be able to bring the screen back by moving the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following instructions:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Screen_Blanks.2BAC8-Monitor_Turns_Off

Note that GDM was replaced by LightDM.